# Unable to save file with other text details from a template, which gives "Required request part 'file' is not present" this error

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

> My Controller

```
@PostMapping
public String registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user,
BindingResult result, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException{

    byte[] pic = file.getBytes();    
    User imageUser = new User(pic);  
    userService.save(user);
    userService.save(imageUser);

    return "redirect:/registration?success";
    }
```

I am saving image from controller and other textual details through service

> My template

```html
<form class="login100-form validate-form" th:action="@{/registration}" th:object="${user}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    //other textual inputs like name address and number
    
<label for="Profile Picture">Profile Picture</label>
<input  type="file" name="file" placeholder="Pofile Picture" th:field="*{pic}">
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `th:field` or use `pic` as the parameter name.

Comment: now it throws an error of multipart request, says "Current request is not a multipart request"